# Best laptop for coding under 1400?

Tags: laptop

Best laptops around 1400?
Something with at least 16 gb of ram
And preferably a dedicated graphics card for simulations and such
Also good build quality is nice

Comment: 1400 of what?  Goats?  Rupees?  Pesos?  Rubles?  Dongs?  Canadian dollars?  American Dollars?  Euros?  Shekels?  Dinars?  Kwachas?  Yuans?  Krones?  Shillings?  Francs?  Quetzals?  Gold coins?  Rubies?  Oysters?  And what are you coding?  And in what language?  How do you define "good" build quality?  I'll give you any laptop you want for 1400 goats. ;)

Answer (score 1):

So for general coding you don't need a dGPU, that's only needed for gamedevelopment. For the budget I'm gonna assume you mean €1400 since it's my local currency and very close to the US dollar.

I use the Framework Laptop 13in (11th gen Intel) DIY edition. The build quality is nice, the RAM and SSD are cheap (if you buy it from a different store like Megekko or Amazon) and it's easy to build. You also are not locked into Windows with this setup, which is nice for development since most ITers have to have some experience with Linux and being able to dualboot or singleboot Linux is also really nice. And also upgrades are cheaper than with other laptop models. It doesn't have a dGPU though but I have heared that the Framework Laptop 16 does get one with similar build quality and RAM upgrade prices

Comment: Update: The Framework Laptop 16 does have an option for a dGPU but is outside of your budget (assuming we calculate in Euro's)